# SQL result not being sent in email

Tags: php

I have a forgot password php page that sends the user his password if his email is in the database. The code is working but the password in the sent email is blank. I think it's cause I haven't converted it to a string but I cant find how to do so. Also I have salted the passwords in the database, is this affecting anything?

The salt:

```html
<?php
  $salt1    = "qm&h*";
  $salt2    = "pg!@";
  $token    = hash('ripemd128', "$salt1$pass$salt2");
?>
```

The forgot password php page:

```html
<?php
$error = $email = "";

if (isset($_POST['email']))
  {
    $email = sanitizeString($_POST['email']);
    
    if ($email == "")
        $error = "Not all fields were entered<br>";
    else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
      $error='Email is invalid';
    else
    {
      $resultE = queryMySQL("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

      $result_pass = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
     $row = $result_pass->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     $user_pass = $row['[pass]'];

      if ($resultE->num_rows == 0)
      {
        $error = "<span class='error'>Email
                  error</span><br><br>";
      }else
      {
        $mail_to = $email;
        $subject = 'This is your registered password ';
        $body_message = 'Password: '."\n\n".$user_pass; //convert to string
        $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message);
        if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) 
           $url = $_SESSION['url'];
        else 
           $url = "../../index.php"; 

        header("Location:$url"); 
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: You can do when forgot email send then new password generate and send email and check with database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the error code

```html
$user_pass = $row['pass'];
```